# Linking an inner component to outer state via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `HomePage` that contains an `ArticleList`.

The `HomePage` makes a network call to get an array of articles from the network.

This array is then added to the redux store.

```
class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    dispatch(loadArticles()); // async network call to fetch articles
  }
  render() {
    <ArticleList articles={this.props.articles} />
  }
}

function ArticleList({articles}) { 
  return <div>articles.forEach(a => <Article value={a} />)</div>;
}
```

Given that `this.props.articles` will not be populated until sometime after the `HomePage` has rendered, will the wire-up above (ie. `<ArticleList articles={this.props.articles} />`) work, or will a callback need to be supplied to `ArticleList` instead?

Comment: Yes. `ArticleList` expects `articles` to be an array, but it is initialliy (before the network request returns) set to an object (a `List` according to the console?!) - and this causes the proptype validation to fail. I have no idea what is setting this value to be a `List`. I set initial value in the store to the empty array, so this is unexpected. I am using sagas. Maybe something is seeing the initial empty array and converting it to a `List`?

Comment: it will totally work, just make sure to set a default value to the `articles` props to avoid calling `forEach` of a null value.

Comment: Also, _do not_ use `forEach` in that example, because it doesn't return anything.  You need to use `map()`: `<div>{articles.map(a => <Article value={a} />}</div>`

Comment: Ah, it is the result of calling `globalState.get('articles')`. It is because I am using Immutable.js and I need to call toJS on the result of the store retrieval. I think.